# Convert Rdd to list

Tags: python, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

how can i convert this Rdd to a list:

```
tfidf.collect()
output:
[DenseVector([0.0619]),
 DenseVector([0.031]),
 DenseVector([0.031]),
 DenseVector([0.031]),
 DenseVector([0.0619]),
 DenseVector([0.031]),
 DenseVector([0.031]),
 DenseVector([0.031]),
 DenseVector([0.031]),
 DenseVector([0.031]),
 DenseVector([0.031]),
 DenseVector([0.031])]
```

And i need to make this Rdd to a similar list as this:

```
tfidf_list= [
    DenseVector([0.0619]),
 DenseVector([0.031]),
 DenseVector([0.031]),
 DenseVector([0.031]),
 DenseVector([0.0619]),
 DenseVector([0.031]),
 DenseVector([0.031]),
 DenseVector([0.031]),
 DenseVector([0.031])
]
```

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
tfidf_list = tfidf.collect()
```